# Retrieving results by running a query based on condition in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

So i have following 2 tables which i am using to write a Book library in Django.

```
class Book(models.Model):
 """Model representing a book (but not a specific copy of a book)."""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text="Enter a brief description of the book",null=True)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, help_text="Select a genre for this book")
    shelflocation = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    pages = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    copies = models.IntegerField(null=True,default=1)
```

and another BookInstance model where i am maintaining both the status and number of copies

```
class BookInstance(models.Model):
    """Model representing a specific copy of a book (i.e. that can be borrowed from the library)."""
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4,
                          help_text="Unique ID for this particular book across whole library")
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    due_back = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    borrower = models.ForeignKey('MemberList',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)

    LOAN_STATUS = (
        ('d', 'Maintenance'),
        ('o', 'On loan'),
        ('a', 'Available'),
        ('r', 'Reserved'),
    )
```

So if a book is loaned then status will be set to 'o' in above table.
I would like to display all the Books of a specific author whose books has been loaned and copies are still available(which is maintained in copies in Book model)

I tried adding queryset to list but it failed. Is there a way to query based on the condition in the following query

```
if book_instance_count < book.copies or book_instance_count == 0:
    bookquery_res = Book.objects.filter(author__icontains=author_name)

    final_book_list = []
    for book in bookquery_res:
        book_instance_count = BookInstance.objects.filter(book_id=book.id).filter(status__exact='o').count()

        if book_instance_count < book.copies or book_instance_count == 0:
            final_book_list.append(list(book))
```

Edit 1

So if the number of copies of a particular Book is 3 and if the number of BookInstance for the same book is 2 then i should display the corresponding book.

**Update**

as a workaround i am calculating the count of each book that is loaned based on author name using following

```
num_books = Count('bookinstance',filter=Q(bookinstance__status__exact='o'))
result =Book.objects.filter(author__icontains=author_name).annotate(num_books=num_books)
```

and using the above result to filter further in HTML rendering  using condition

> (result.copies > result.num_books)

Comment: What do you mean by "it failed"? What was the exact error? Please add the full error stacktrace if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

You're making things too complicated. You can do this directly in a single query.

```
Book.objects.filter(
    author__icontains=author_name
).filter(
    bookinstance__status="o"
).filter(bookinstance__status="a")
```

which will find all books from that author with at least one available instance and at least one onloan instance.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.but there is a tricky bit here, which is the number of copies. The if condition within the loop is where I am stuck. How can I use that in my objects filter is the question.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be an annotated query, displaying only books that have both available and loaned book instances:

```
from django.db import models

Book.objects\
    .annotate(
        on_loan=Coalesce(
            models.Sum(
                models.Case(
                    models.When(
                        bookinstance__status='o',
                        then=1))),
            0),
        available=Coalesce(
            models.Sum(
                models.Case(
                    models.When(
                        bookinstance__status='a',
                        then=1))),
            0))\
    .filter(author__icontains=author_name, on_loan__gt=0, available__gt=0)
```

You can read about [`.annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate), [`Coalesce`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) and others.

Comment: Thanks Ralf. But the above filter doesn't address the number of copies on loan and actual copies in Book object